# How to achieve group by like functionality in excel

Tags: excel

Please see below an image to demonstrate this problem.

Is there any functionality within excel such that if the attribute column is set to 'total', the value column will be populated automatically, by summing attribute1 and attribute2 for the given id?

Any tips would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Doable with VBA perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim RngAttributes As Range
    Dim RngIDs
    Dim RngValues
    Dim RngFocus As Range
    Dim StrTrigger As String
    Dim StrAttribute1 As String
    Dim StrAttribute2 As String
    Dim DlbFirstRow As Double
    
    Set RngIDs = Range("A:A")
    Set RngAttributes = Range("B:B")
    Set RngValues = Range("C:C")
    StrTrigger = "total"
    StrAttribute1 = "attribute1"
    StrAttribute2 = "attribute2"
    
    Set RngAttributes = Intersect(Target, RngAttributes)
    DlbFirstRow = RngIDs.Row
    
    If Not (RngAttributes Is Nothing) Then
        For Each RngFocus In RngAttributes
            If RngFocus.Value = VBA.Strings.LCase(StrTrigger) Or _
               RngFocus.Value = VBA.Strings.UCase(StrTrigger) Or _
               RngFocus.Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Proper(StrTrigger) Then
                Cells(RngFocus.Row, RngValues.Column).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(R" & DlbFirstRow & "C:R" & RngFocus.Row - 1 & "C,R" & DlbFirstRow & "C" & RngIDs.Column & ":R" & RngFocus.Row - 1 & "C" & RngIDs.Column & ",RC" & RngIDs.Column & ",R" & DlbFirstRow & "C" & RngAttributes.Column & ":R" & RngFocus.Row - 1 & "C" & RngAttributes.Column & ",""" & StrAttribute1 & """) + SUMIFS(R" & DlbFirstRow & "C:R" & RngFocus.Row - 1 & "C,R" & DlbFirstRow & "C" & RngIDs.Column & ":R" & RngFocus.Row - 1 & "C" & RngIDs.Column & ",RC" & RngIDs.Column & ",R" & DlbFirstRow & "C" & RngAttributes.Column & ":R" & RngFocus.Row - 1 & "C" & RngAttributes.Column & ",""" & StrAttribute2 & """)"
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
End Sub
```